# Java Execute Interrupt Method when breakpoint is hit

Tags: java

I am not sure if this is even possible, but here goes:

How can one execute a specific method when a certain breakpoint condition is set? I am trying to start/pause a process over UDP.

The process gives me data that needs to be validated. There is no synchronization between the running of the process and my java application. If the java application stops in a breakpoint, the process will still continue sending me data.

How would a synchronization mechanism look like?

Comment: Did I understand you correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Eclipse, when the breakpoint is hit, open the `Display` view and execute your desired code there.

Everything there works on the context of the current line.